# Does Haxe have pointers or references?

Tags: pointers, reference, haxe

I've been looking trough the documentation of Haxe and can't really find a definitive answer on whether there are pointers or references in Haxe.

Comment: AFAIK, you will only find the term 'pointer' being used with specific platforms, ie- cpp pointer, or cs pointer. Things are done for you when it comes to memory, because different platforms typically do it differently. It might not be what you want, but the syntax void->void is a type that holds a function with no args and no return type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

References.  Haxe doesn't expose raw memory locations, since many targets don't allow it.  The one exception may be using special workarounds on special targets.

Comment: This indeed makes sense since it has multiple target languages. After a little more searching I found there to be a platform specific pointer for the cpp target. http://api.haxe.org/cpp/Pointer.html